# How to pass command-line arguments to AHK script?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to run the AHK script with arguments, like:

```
AutoHotkeyU64 file.ahk arg1 arg2
```

Then access these variables as part of the script, e.g.

```
MsgBox, %arg1%, %arg2%
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command line parameters are stored in the variables `%1%`, `%2%`, and so on. So for example:

```
MsgBox, %1%, %2%
```

Since version [v1.1.27+](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm#v1.1.27.00), input parameters are stored as an array in the built-in variable `A_Args` as an [array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays).

Here is the example:

```
for n, param in A_Args  ; For each parameter:
{
    MsgBox Parameter number %n% is %param%.
}
```

> **Legacy**: The command line parameters are also stored in the variables `%1%`, `%2%`, and so on, as in versions prior to [v1.1.27]. In addition, `%0%` contains the number of parameters passed (0 if none). However, these variables cannot be referenced directly in an expression because they would be seen as numbers rather than variables.

Source: [Passing Command Line Parameters to a Script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd).

Comment: The first argument is `A_Args[1]` and so on

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

In AutoHotkey, %1%, %2% and so on are the command line arguements that have been given.
Lets say we have a script called script.ahk, and inside of that script we have `MsgBox, %1%`

if I were to type `script.ahk hey`, we would get a messagebox with hey in it.
[Demo Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqwsv.png)

Hopefully that helps :-)

Comment: This is not precisely true. It seems it works if you run a compiled version of the script (.exe) but not the .ahk source directly.